# Whats the easiest way to get a table DDL from an orc file?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, bigdata, orc

With spark I can do for example:

`spark.read.orc("/path/to/file").printSchema`

But I would like to get something like the output of `show create table` in hive. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should handle most cases (tailor it to your specific case if needed):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, BooleanType, DoubleType, IntegerType, LongType, StringType, StructField}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    val types = spark.read.orc("/path/to/orc/orc_file.orc").schema
    println("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE name (")
    types.foreach {
      //case (name, typ) => println("    " + name + " " + getType(typ))
      case StructField(name, dataType, nullable, metadata) =>
        println("  " + name.toLowerCase + " " + getType(dataType) + ",")
    }
    println(")")
  }

  def getType(typ: Any): String = {
    typ match {
      case StringType => "string"
      case IntegerType => "int"
      case DoubleType => "double"
      case LongType => "bigint"
      case BooleanType => "boolean"
      case ArrayType(elementType, containsNull) => "array<" + getType(elementType) + ">"
      case StructField(name, dataType, nullable, metadata) => s"${name.toLowerCase}:${getType(dataType)}"
      case seq: Seq[StructField] => "struct<" + seq.map(e => getType(e)).mkString(",") + ">"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the intent of the above output?  The solution is not complete as it does not provide information about TBLPROPERTIES, SERDEPROPERTIES and path of the underlying data.

Comment: TBLPROPERTIES are for a table. Why would they be stored in an ORC file? Maybe some things could be stored. This code generates the main part of the DDL: create table name (col string, col2 int, col3 struct<col4:string, col5:int>) for example, the hard work. The rest can be added by hand.

Comment: I personally had a file with over 100 columns and the types were complex, struct<bla bla bla>. And a huge amount of nesting for those structs as well.